# filled ExtJs columns json

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have a greed with columns. And have a jsp which do json data. im jet this json in my js and do `Ext.data.JsonStore` but its not getting in columns.

store

```
store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
url: url_servlet+'Kadastr.jsp',
    fields: [
        {name: 'indoor', type: 'bool'},
        {name: 'kad_id', type: 'integer'},
        {name: 'kad_name',type: 'string'}
    ]
});
store.load();
```

columns

```
var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        header: '',
        dataIndex: 'indoor',
        width: 50
    }, {
        header: 'id',
        dataIndex: 'kad_id',
        width: 70
    },{
        id: 'kad_name',
        header: 'Участок',
        dataIndex: 'common',
        width: 130,
        }]
})
```

gridpanel

```
var kad_tab = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    cm: cm,
    id: 'kad_greed',
    title:'Список Участков',
    autoScroll: true,
```

java code

```
            JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
    resultJson.put("indoor",new Boolean(false));
    resultJson.put("kad_name",fileName);
    resultJson.put("kad_id",new Integer(fileId));
            out.println(resultJson.toString());
```

Any idias? what can i foggoten to add?

Comment: When is your store.load() call happening?  Has the store loaded because you create the GridPanel?

Comment: `store.load();` in first code fragment.

Comment: I try add `Ext.data.JsonReader` but nothing to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store reader expects an array of items, as i see you are sending just one record.
so instead of : `{"indoor":false,"kad_name":"filename"..}` you should send an array and a root object. Something like:

`{"values":[{"indoor":false,"kad_name":"filename"..}]}` and then just add root "values" to the jsonreader. Default root is "" so you can send it with default blank.